# How to loop through an array in componentDidMount()?

Tags: reactjs

I'm learning more ReactJS, and trying to display data from my example API.

I'm able to display one title, but I can't figure out how to loop through the array, and display all the titles?

Currently I can display one event title, e.g. "Event1", but I would like to display, e.g.

```
  Event1
  Event2
  Event3
  ...
```

Here is my app.js:

```
class App extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      title: ''
    }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    var th = this;
    this.serverRequest = 
      axios.get(this.props.source)
        .then(function(event) {    
          th.setState({
            title: event.data[0].title[0].value
          });
        })
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    this.serverRequest.abort();
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>Here you can see one event title:</h1>
        <h2>{this.state.title}</h2>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
    <App source="http://localhost:8888/my/api/events" />,
     document.getElementById('container')
);
```

And here is my index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>App</title>
</head>
<body>

<div id="container"></div>

<script src="https://npmcdn.com/react@15.3.1/dist/react.js"></script>
<script src="https://npmcdn.com/react-dom@15.3.1/dist/react-dom.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/axios/dist/axios.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-core/5.8.24/browser.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/babel" src="js/app.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Here is a console.log() of the data I get from my API:

[image]

How could I loop through the array, to display all the titles, and not just one? With map(), or adding a for loop in componentDidMount()?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change `axios.get` to store all the data you received from server in `this.state.data`:

```
axios.get(this.props.source)
     .then(function(event) {    
          th.setState({
            data: event.data
          });
      })
```

Iterate through it:

```
render() {
    var titles = []
    this.state.data.forEach(item => {
       titles.push(<h2>{item.title[0].value}</h2>)
    })
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>Here you can see all titles :)</h1>
        {titles}
      </div>
    );
}
```

or

```
render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>Here you can see all titles :)</h1>
        {this.state.data.map(function(item){
           return <h2>{item.title[0].value}</h2>
         })}
      </div>
    );
}
```